# CDN Farfuture URLs not be working with Fastly, if enabled cacheable forever checkbox

Tags: drupal, cdn, fastly

Many thanks for your reply to my query, I want to ask you one more points on #1. Below is details for my query/issue:

On point #1, we can see this is "x-cache: MISS" in the response headers; we get the same behavior when requesting a given URL for the first time, so it does not appear to be a cached response. This is an existing site; we see this issue only with the combination of the Fastly domain and the farfuture feature enabled. It looks like Drupal might be issuing the 302 redirect, possibly to the root of the site, but I don't know how we can verify that.
Here is our settings from Drupal config for File System:
Public file system path
sites/us/files
Public file base URL
https://origin-domain.com/us/sites/us/files
Here are four different ways to request the same image; only the combination mentioned above is failing (i.e. get 302 redirect):
Working:
https://origin-domain.com/us/cdn/farfuture/7fPXsGzPQo7CUdilOBMTARjP_snit...
NOT working:
https://cdn-domain.com/us/cdn/farfuture/7fPXsGzPQo7CUdilOBMTARjP_snit7D3...
Working:
https://origin-domain.com/us/sites/us/files/coperta_30.jpg
Working:
https://cdn-domain.com/us/sites/us/files/coperta_30.jpg

Br,
Kapil P

Answer (score 0):

Issue title: Fastly CDN-forever cachable issue

Issue description:

Hi team

I am using Faslty CDN network for my application, in which having issue in thumbnail creation and upload image on it.

I am using Drupal 8 version and CDN module to setup Fastly CDN configuration, When am upload image through CDN path it's upload file inside folder /Files/image.png, but at same time image is not uploading into thumbnail folder. But am disabled CDN configuration then image is uploading on both folder /files/ and /thumbnail/.

Below is details description with image path.

1.) works: https://cdn-doamin.com/us/sites/us/files/NorbFastlyTestThree_0.jpg
Not work: https://cdn-domain.com/us/sites/us/files/styles/thumbnail/public/NorbFas...

How does Drupal validate itok?

2.) works: https://cdn-domain.com/us/sites/us/files/coperta_30.jpg
Not working: https://cdn-domaine.com/us/cdn/farfuture/7fPXsGzPQo7CUdilOBMTARjP_snit7D...

Question about "forever cachable" - How does Drupal take the "/farfuture/dhsdhsadhjsbfbdueiu/" and know how to handle that?

Thanks,